# Draggable Indirect Excel

Tags: excel, excel-indirect

I have this formula:

```
=IF($C7="Y",INDIRECT("'"&$A7&"'!D$12"),0)
```

But I want to make the `D` in `D$12` draggable. I've tried adding `&` but it's not working.

The `A7` portion is draggable, which I want.

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use following formula

```
=IF($C7="Y",INDIRECT("'" & $A7 & "'!" & CELL("address",D$12)),0)
```